# Docker build images and run but gives Error response from daemon: i/o timeout error after 5 minutes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build and run 8 docker images via docker-compose. Some of them Java Spring projects and some of them angular projects. I am working under corporate proxy. I set proxy settings and docker works correctly. I can build and run images via **docker-compose up -d --build** command. I can see the logs at first. However after 3-5 minutes, when I tried to run **docker ps** or **docker logs** commands I got this error: **Error response from daemon: i/o timeout** . I tried to find the solution but every question was about the problem occurs during build process which is not my case.

Every time I restart docker, down the services then run the services without problem but after 5 minutes I can not run any docker command. How can I permanently fix this issue. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It could be an issue with disk storage. Can you check and see if any thing is 100% filled in `df -h` command when you encounter "Error response from daemon: i/o timeout"

Comment: Check and share the logs, there might be some relevant stuff there.